# django can't import in installed apps and can't import function

Tags: python, django

In Django, I have a "fbsurvey" project, with a "canvas" application.

I have another "cblib" project, with a "survey" app and a "graphs" app.

In the "survey" app, there are models and some functions.
In the "graphs" app, there is just a "utils" folder with 2 .py files in it-- a file "get_chart_info" with a function "get_chart_info" and a file "chart_utils" with some assorted functions in it

graphs app has an **init**.py on each level
all of the models in "survey" work

but "get_chart_info" (the file) REFUSES to import.

If I try to put "cblib.graphs" in my installed apps, when I try to runserver, it breaks, saying "Error: No module named graphs"

If I leave it out of my installed apps, I get:
ImportError at /canvas/chart/
No module named graphs.utils.get_chart_info
(btw, I don't understand why this says no module named graphs.utils instead of cblib.graphs.utils)

with a line reference to the import statement.

Note that all of the imports work in the shell. I.e. when I run:
./manage.py shell
import cblib
import cblib.survey
import cblib.graphs
import cblib.graphs.get_chart_info
from cblib.graphs.get_chart_info import get_chart_info

nothing fails.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be breaking? I feel like I've checked everything.

someone mentioned it might be useful to see the ascii tree of my project (edited for relevance)

cblib looks like:

```
.
├── graphs
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── utils
│       ├── get_chart_info.py
│       ├── get_chart_info.pyc
│       ├── graph_utils.py
│       ├── graph_utils.pyc
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── __init__.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
└── survey
    ├── admin.py
    ├── fixtures
    │   ├── badges.json
    │   ├── q1-174.json
    │   ├── q175-271.json
    │   ├── q272-302.json
    │   └── responseoptions_767-1594.json
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── management
    │   ├── commands
    │   │   ├── create_fake_users.py
    │   │   ├── import_fake_user_data.py
    │   │   ├── import_questions.py
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0002_auto__del_field_votelog_direction.py
    │   ├── 0003_auto__chg_field_pointlog_action_type.py
    │   ├── 0004_auto__add_opengraphverb__add_field_question_school_specific_opengraph_.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── models
        ├── badge.py
        ├── badge.pyc
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── opengraphverb.py
        ├── opengraphverb.pyc
        ├── pointlog.py
        ├── pointlog.pyc
        ├── question.py
        ├── question.pyc
        ├── responseoption.py
        ├── responseoption.pyc
```

and fbsurvey looks like:

```
.
├── canvas
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── brainys.json
│   ├── data.csv
│   ├── decorators.py
│   ├── decorators.pyc
│   ├── DefaultInfoObject.py
│   ├── DefaultInfoObject.pyc
│   ├── DefaultJsonResponse.py
│   ├── DefaultJsonResponse.pyc
│   ├── fixtures
│   │   └── test-fixture.json
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── level.py
│   ├── level.pyc
│   ├── management
│   │   ├── commands
│   │   │   ├── convert_fbuser_to_cbuser.pyc
│   │   │   ├── credit_inviters.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── reminder_wallposts.py
│   │   │   ├── reminder_wallposts.pyc
│   │   │   └── update_user_colleges.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   └── js
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── answers.html
│   │   ├── answers-mobile.html
│   │   ├── answertest.html
│   │   ├── badge-explanation.html
│   │   ├── badges.html
│   │   ├── baduser.html
│   │   ├── bottombar.html
│   │   ├── bottombar-mobile.html
│   │   ├── browse-stories.html
│   │   ├── end.html
│   │   ├── friends.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── tests.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views
│   │   ├── answers.py
│   │   ├── answers.pyc
│   │   ├── badge_explanation.py
│   │   ├── badge_explanation.pyc
│   │   ├── badges.py
│   │   ├── badges.pyc
│   │   ├── browse_stories.py
│   │   ├── browse_stories.pyc
│   │   ├── explanation.pyc
│   │   ├── format_for_graph.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── local_settings.py
├── local_settings.pyc
├── local_settings.py.example
├── logclient
│   └── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── maps.py
├── maps.pyc
├── patch.py
├── pokesite
├── python.exe.stackdump
├── README
├── requirements.txt
├── settings.py
├── settings.pyc
├── survey
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── CBI Questions with percentages v3.csv
│   │   ├── data.csv
│   │   ├── List of School Nicknames.txt
│   │   ├── pquestions.csv
│   │   ├── question_pks_and_categories.csv
│   │   ├── questions.csv
│   │   └── questions.json
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── localsetting.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── surveydump.json
├── sync_badges.py
├── templates
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── base.html
│   └── base-mobile.html
├── testdump.json
├── tree.txt
├── urls.py
└── urls.pyc
```

Comment: what does your settings.py look like? have you added everything?

Comment: my fbsurvey settings.py hasn't changed from before I added the graphs app (and everything was working). Cblib doesn't have a settings because it's a library.

Comment: I think you probably need to register the apps in settings. How else would your project know where to pull from? You might wanna figure out the overall architecture of your project. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069254/access-models-in-other-project-in-a-django-view-cause-table-doesnt-exist-erro

Comment: well, as I said, "If I try to put "cblib.graphs" in my installed apps, when I try to runserver, it breaks, saying "Error: No module named graphs"

Comment: So when you say you put "cblib.graphs", cblib is its own project, but you want to access the app via fbsurvey, correct? You have to either copy over the apps from cblib to fbsurvey, and register the app in settings.py of fbsurvey, OR register the app in settings using a PYTHONPATH hack as mentioned in the above link. You can always check for things like this in the shell ("python manage.py shell" from your project)

Comment: I DID REGISTER THE APP IN SETTINGS, using INSTALLED_APPS. ALL OF MY OTHER APPS ARE REGISTERED VIA INSTALLED_APPS, AND THEY ALL WORK. I DO NOT need to "copy over the apps from cblib to fbsurvey"-- what would be the point of putting them in settings if I needed to copy them over? Please stop commenting, you clearly don't know what you're talking about. P.s. I HAVE tested the imports in the shell, and they work.

Comment: Also please READ THE WHOLE QUESTION before commenting, if you don't it's worse than saying nothing at all.

Comment: @Colleen people is trying to help and I can tell you it is not easy because your answer lacks of proper explanation (aka source code [ ascii tree of your project]) caps lock off please :)

Comment: As I said, it's not helpful if people don't read the whole question, or my responses. If there's something else I need to put in the question, that's fine, but "answering" without reading is worse than not answering at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was something to do with my .pyc files... I don't know how or why, but running

find . -name "*.pyc" -delete

(which then presumably regenerated my pyc files)
in both of my project directories fixed the problem.

Comment: this command just delete old unused .pyc files in wrong places and does not generate new

Comment: but new ones are generated when I run my application.