# Accessing Sentry models in my Django Project

Tags: django, orm, subprocess, sentry

I'm working on a system that has two django projects. A server and a client. The server is responsible for managing several client instances. This system relies on Sentry/Raven to process error logging.

My problem is that Sentry needs me to create and configure each client(sentry project) by hand. Since the number of client instances is large and I already have to do this by hand on my server project. I was trying to automatize the process, so that when I create a new client on the server, it creates a new Sentry project.

Much like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069254/access-models-in-other-project-in-a-django-view-cause-table-doesnt-exist-erro), I tried to access directly to the Sentry ORM on my project. But this revealed to be a dead end. So I wrote a python scrypt, to do this.

In said script, I import the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE from sentry and work my way around with it until I have what I need.

```
sys.path.append("/sentry/")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", 'sentry_configuration_file')

from sentry.models import *

#Do my thing here
```

If I run the script on my shell, it works perfectly.

However, when I use subprocess to call it inside of my Django project

```
from subprocess import call
call("/sentry/venv/bin/python /sentry/my_script.py", shell=True)
```

The script generates the following error on the "from sentry.models import * line:

```
ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'configurations.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named configurations.settings
```

You may have noticed that sentry is installed inside a virtualenv. However, I don't need it activated when I call this script on my bash, as long as I provide the correct path to the virtualenv's python.

I'm lost here. I see no reason in particular for the script to fail using subprocess.call when it runs fine using the shell.

Any pointers would be greatly apreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone ever comes across with this question, I managed to solve the issue by replacing subprocess.call by subprocess.Popen

The cool thing about Popen is that you can specify the environment of the process with the argument "env"

So

```
my_env = os.environ
my_env["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "sentry_configuration_file"

result = Popen(command, shell=True, env=my_env)
```

Worked like a charm.